# HTML element alignment in container is thrown off by adding of text to some and not others

Tags: html

When two HTML elements are put in the same container, one containing text and the other not containing text, the text messes with their alignment. The element with the text will drop down so that the bottom of the text aligns with the bottom of the element with no text, as in this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div>
  <button style= "width:100px;height:100px;"></button>
  <button style= "width:100px;height:100px;">text</button>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Adding or removing text from both elements aligns them correctly, but is there a way to get the elements to align without adding text to both?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the container a flex container to achieve this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
  <button style= "width:100px;height:100px;"></button>
  <button style= "width:100px;height:100px;">text</button>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix it with vertical-align:top as I did here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div>
  <button style= "width:100px;height:100px;"></button>
  <button style= "width:100px;height:100px; vertical-align:top">text</button>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```